# Can I reference a previously defined function in an if/else conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

Before I begin I'd like to state that I'm a total beginner to HTML/JS/web development in general. Please keep this in mind when you look at my code! I'm currently building a simple website where the user inputs some text, which generates a bunch of follow-up text related to the input. I used JavaScript to display the input and the follow-up text once the 'submit' button has been pressed.
What I'd like to do now is create an if/else statement that decides which follow-up text will display based on the input; so for example, if the user typed in a specific phrase, the follow-up text which relates to the phrase would also display on the page; but if the user typed in another specific phrase, there would be another block of follow-up text that relates to the second specific phrase.

However, when I try to write an if/else statement, the functions that I previously defined aren't being called within the statement. I figure this is to do with the scope of the functions, but I don't know how to fix that issue. It's also entirely possible that my code is bad or I made some mistake, but I've reached a bit of a dead end, which is why I'm turning to you guys!

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  //onClick allows the Input and the follow up text to post at the same time

  function onClick() {
    showInput();
    antiEuropeExample();
  }
  //showInput returns the user input (check the HTML below)

  function showInput() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = document.getElementById(
      "user_input"
    ).value;
  }

  //Insane hard coding here, I'm so sorry

  function antiEuropeExample() {
    document.getElementById("twt_1").innerHTML =
      "I hate the EU! We need to get rid of it. ";
    document.getElementById("twt_2").innerHTML =
      "I hope Europe sinks into the sea.";
  }

  //this if-else statement isn't working cos of scope issues i guess??? i want an if/else statement to decide which block of code should execute depending on what the user types into the input.

  /*
  function onClick() {
    if ((showInput = "I hate the EU!")) {
      antiEuropeExample;
    } else {
      alert("It worked!");
    }
  }
  */
</script>
```

NOTE: The first 'onClick' function works but please ignore it for the sake of this question; the second 'onClick' function that is commented out is the one that I'm having problems with. Also if anyone has any tips to clean up my syntax that would be super appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @Flater's answer is the correct solution to the question you have asked. But there is another bug in your code as you are confusing the assignment operator (`=`) with the equality operator (`==` or `===`). If you want to ask "are these two things the same" you need the latter.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a method, you have to add `()` parentheses. Without parentheses, you are passing the method around as a reference. With parentheses, you are telling the code to run the method and get the result (if the method returns anything).

```
function onClick() {
    if (showInput() === "I hate the EU!"){   // <---- Notice the ()
        antiEuropeExample();                // <---- Notice the ()
    } else {
        alert("This guy loves the EU");
    }
}
```

Yes, even when the method has no parameters, you *have* to use the parentheses. Otherwise the runtime doesn't actually know that the method should be executed, instead of being passed around like a reference.

---

As an aside, you were using `=` in your `if` statement, but it should have been `==` or `===`.

`=` is the assignment operator. It doesn't check for equality, it sets [left] thing to the value of [right].

`==` checks for equality, and is very forgiving in terms of data types.

`===` checks for equality, but only allows the exact same data type. Otherwise, it will not find a match.

Comment: ahaa thank you! i knew there was something dodgy. i'll try that out and see if it works! thank you again!